# faceted piechart with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, pie-chart

I've done a faceted piechart with ggplot2 like this:

```
qplot(x=factor(1), data=mtcars, fill=factor(cyl)) + 
    geom_bar(width=1) +  
    coord_polar(theta="y") + 
    facet_grid(~gear)
```

[image]

but as all the piecharts share the y axis scale, some of them doesn't cover the full circle. I've tried with `facet_grid(~gear, scales="free")` but it doesn't work.

How could I get full circles for all the piecharts?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think you just want `position = 'fill'`:

```
ggplot(mtcars,aes(x = factor(1),fill=factor(cyl))) + 
    facet_wrap(~gear) + 
    geom_bar(width = 1,position = "fill") + 
    coord_polar(theta="y")
```

For future reference, from the Details section of `geom_bar`:

> By default, multiple x's occuring in the same place will be stacked a
>   top one another by position_stack. If you want them to be dodged from
>   side-to-side, see position_dodge. Finally, position_fill shows
>   relative propotions at each x by stacking the bars and then stretching
>   or squashing to the same height.

Comment: I feel somewhat guilty upvoting a piechart answer.

Comment: ^^ To be fair, the same issue occurs when `coord_polar` is omitted.

Comment: This solve the problem partially because the y axis now measure relative frequencies and I want the counts.

Comment: @Alf Setting aside for the moment that what you propose is a terrible idea and would make for a really bad plot, I don't think you'll be able to do that very easily, since ggplot does not support free scales in non-cartesian coordinates.

Comment: When I use geom_text, the problem reappears, even with position = "fill". Do you know why @joran ?

Comment: Update: It works when I input position = "fill" into geom_text!

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for another convenient way to do this, you can have a look at the `ggstatsplot` package, both the bar and the pie charts.

```r
# setup
set.seed(123)
library(ggstatsplot)

# pie chart
ggpiestats(mtcars, gear, cyl)

#> Warning in stats::chisq.test(x = data$main, y = data$condition, correct =
#> FALSE, : Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect
```

[image]

```r
# bar chart
ggbarstats(mtcars, gear, cyl)
#> Warning in stats::chisq.test(x = data$main, y = data$condition, correct =
#> FALSE, : Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-06-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>