# How to make a pie chart with ggplot2?

Tags: r, charts, ggplot2, pie-chart

I am trying to plot a pie chart using the following dataset

```
dt <- data.frame(name= c("A", "B", "C"),
           one = sample(1:10, 3),
           two= sample(1:10, 3),
           three =sample(1:10, 3))
```

Of course the data are untidy, so I rearrange the dataset in a longitudinal form using

```
library(dplyr)
dt <- dt %>% gather("letter")
colnames(dt)[2]  <- "number"
```

And I am perfectly able to plot a barchart

```
library(ggplot2)   
ggplot(dt, aes(x=letter, y=value, fill=number)) + 
geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

But when I apply the coord_polar() transformation, I can't make the slices look even nor make the pie-chart to sum up to 100%

```
ggplot(dt, aes(x=letter, y=value, fill=number)) + 
geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
coord_polar(theta = "x")
```

[image: Here is the output I get]

Comment: If you're trying to make three pie charts, then this looks like a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18537378/faceted-piechart-with-ggplot2)

Comment: I know I'm biased but for the love of Henry give `waffle::waffle()` a go instead of pie charts.

Comment: @hrbrmstr thanks for the reference, yet I was simply trying to practice with transformations while reading the grammar of graphics; I didn't mean to offend anyone while asking about pie charts :)

Comment: @aosmith I tried to clarify in the comments to @ bunk's response what I was trying to do, sorry for being unclear