# Pie Chart in ggplot2 picking single samples from a dataframe

Tags: r, ggplot2, pie-chart

I would like to produce a simple pie chart from my dataframe, which has multiple samples.

A sample dataframe looks like this:

```
Sample <- c("S1", "S2", "S3")
Var1 <- c(4,5,3)
Var2 <- c(1,9,4)
Var3 <- c(2,1,3)
df <- data.frame(Sample, Var1, Var2, Var3)
```

I would like to plot a pie chart for each sample. In excel, this is pretty easy and straight forward and looks like the following.

[image: Excel Example]

How can I produce something similar using *ggplot2*?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22592789/faceted-piechart-with-ggplot/22598209 For more options try searching "ggplot facet pie chart"

Comment: My problem is not with faceting the plots, but in creating the individual plots from my dataframe.

Comment: Does this do what you want then? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42489277/multiple-ggplot-pie-charts-with-whole-pies What exactly did you try? Where are you getting stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data just seems to be in a non-tidy format. It's easier to plot it if you reshape it. Here's an example using `tidyr`

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-Sample) %>% 
  ggplot() + 
    aes(x="", y=value, fill=name) + 
    geom_col(position="fill") + 
    facet_wrap(~Sample) + 
    coord_polar("y")
```

Comment: I would have one more question. Is it also possible to add the percentages of the fields to the plot? Maybe even only if they are above a certain threshold (i.e. above 10%)? I have found some solutions to this question, but only for single pie charts, not facetted ones.

Also, my real data is already in percent, so I would not need to calculate the percentage, only paste the corresponding values as text into the fields.